# Ionic button after text area won’t show up

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I don’t know if this is a bug. After I googled I found someone who also has this issue.

Below is the code:

```html
<div class="list list-inset">
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Id" ng-model="Id"/>
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title"/>
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <textarea placeholder="Description" rows="15" ng-model="description"/>
    </label>
    <button class="button button-clear">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `<textarea>` is not a self-closing tag. It should be `<textarea></textarea>`.

Comment: Alrighty, then I’ll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<textarea placeholder="Description"  rows="15" ng-model="description" />
```

This textarea appears to be self-closing. This however cannot be the case because `<textarea>`s require an end tag `</textarea>`, otherwise everything after the opening tag will be interpreted as the contents of the textarea and not be parsed as HTML.

So the correct way of writing it is:

```html
<textarea placeholder="Description" rows="15" ng-model="description"></textarea>
```